# Angular2 - chunk failed error

Tags: angular, build

I am using angular2 with webpack version: 3.11.0. 
Angular cli : 2.3.1

I have created a build using **ng build** command as usual. But after deploying it in server, while routing to some menu items, the following errors occurs:

```
vendor.6e96d626475ec727c65d.bundle.js:1235 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.
Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.
```

Can anyone tells what is the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5964

Comment: Are you loading yours modules lazily ?

Comment: Yes lazily.....

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the exception throws from the router module. As a solution to this, We can catch this exception like below:

```
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

clickMenu(state, child = '') {
    this.router.navigate([state + '/' + child]).then(()=>{
        this.displayLoader--;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Router navigate err");
        console.log(err);
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

The problem is server dependent. ie the same build is throwing the error in the testing server but not in local and production servers.